# Generate all subsets of an array

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic

I'm working on generating all possible subsets of an array. I am working on a recursive solution where I maintain an index that I increment at each step. After incrementing the index, I pop off the last element. I don't understand why the last element in the array gets duplicated.

```
class Solution(object):
  def subsets(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    # You need to keep track of a list of all the subarrays, the current subarray, the index and the original array
    return self.helper(nums, 0, [], [])


  def helper(self, nums, index, fullSol, curr):
    fullSol.append(list(curr)) # add this current array to the list of all subarrays
    print(fullSol)

    # Iterate through the indices
    for i in range(index, len(nums)): 
        curr.append(nums[index]) # add the next element to the current list
        self.helper(nums, i+1, fullSol, curr) # increment the index
        curr = curr[:-1] # remove the last element from the current subarray
```

Comment: `curr.append` mutates the object, but `curr = curr[:-1]` creates a new one. The `append` calls are never really reversed.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `helper` needs `return fullSol` at the end.

Comment: The generated output is the following  '[[]]
[[], [1]]
[[], [1], [1, 2]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 3]]
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 1, 1]]'  This shows that instead of removing the last number it duplicates the 2 @user2357112